# how to save <html contenteditable> content as text file

Tags: javascript, file, url, save, bookmarklet

i saw the content editable url trick from https://coderwall.com/p/lhsrcq

```
    data:text/html, <html contenteditable>
```

it lets you use the browser as a txt file but content is lost when you save the html page.

i've made a string that can be used as a bookmarklet that lets you save what you were typing by creating an iframe with src like

```
    data: Content-type: application/octet-stream
```

plus the contents of the contenteditable element in the browser url

you can see my code at http://pastebin.com/4z8tttuA then copy it into your browser url

my problems are

1. all of the spaces get turned into ' ' and the carriage returns disappear. this is when my content editable element is a div. i tried it with a textarea it also doesn't work
2. name the file something other than 'download' (which later becomes download(1), download(2)...)

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer thanks for correction .@billybradley use stack snippets while editing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cleaned up and fixed what you had, here: http://pastebin.com/sJXVvRUB

I *think* it does what you want. You still have to restyle the link to look like a button, if you want. I've also only tested in Chrome, so it may need other small modifications.

As for your problems and how I fixed them:

1. I'm not sure I completely understand the "spaces" part of the problem, unless you meant that all consecutive whitespace gets (incorrectly) saved as a single space. That's how HTML renders it, actually. I fixed that by replacing your `note = note.replace("&nbsp;", "");` with `note = note.replace('&nbsp;', ' ');`. You were replacing non-breaking spaces with nothing. For line breaks, I just escaped the note before saving: `escape(note)`. I also tweaked the calls to `replace()` to be a bit simpler and more targeted (at least on Chrome).
2. For controlling the filename, I replaced the form+button with a link so I could use the "download" attribute, documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/a#attr-download (also mostly only supported by Chrome at the moment).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for this. Is there a limit on data which we can pass in the HREF attribute?

Comment: @iAnuj, do you mean the amount of data or the type? It looks like you can also pass binary data, though I'm not certain if there's a size/length limit, and if there is, whether it would be browser or machine-dependent. Experiment!

Comment: I was asking about the amount of data, whether it can handle a blog post or a diary entry. I guess I have to make a demo and check it. Thanks :-)